# Where msdev is located

Tags: msdev

I have a 3rd party product that tries to execute msdev, but it cannot be found.

I have two versions of Visual Studio (6 and 9) installed on my desktop.

Comment: VC6 executable is msdev and for VC9 it is devenv. So it should work. Check your path variable contains the path for the executable or not.

Comment: You're right. Visual Studio doesn't need msdev/devenv in path